# What's wrong with this foreach?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm trying to make a function which will use a `foreach` to determine whether the string supplied to it contains any words from an array. I've tried debugging by putting `echo "iteration...<br>";` after the `foreach` so I can see how many times it loops, and it doesn't seem to ever begin looping, so I'm assuming there's a problem with the way I've setup my `foreach` or maybe my array. Any ideas? Thanks.

```
$badwords = array("example", "word");

function containsBad($st) {
    $isbad = false;
    foreach($badwords as $word) {
        echo "iteration...<br>";
        if (strpos($st, $word)) {
            $isbad = true;
        }
    }
    return $isbad ? 'true' : 'false';
}

echo containsBad("example");
```

Comment: `$badwords` is a global. You have to add `global $badwords;` to your function.

Comment: `strpos()` can return 0 (when a keyword is found) or false (when its not found), there's a big warning about this in the [PHP Docs](http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) with an explanation of how to use the function properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must define `$badwords` variable as global inside the function before you use it:

```
global $badwords;
```

But there is another improvements in your program:

1. your program can't determine if bad word begins at the beginning of your string.
2. Using of boolean variable `$isbad`

$badwords = array("example", "word");

```
function containsBad($st) 
  {
  global $badwords;
  $isbad = false;
  foreach($badwords as $word) 
    {
    echo "iteration...<br>";
    if (strpos($st, $word)!==false) 
      $isbad = true;
    }
    return $isbad;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. Weird that you have to do that.

Comment: Basically it doesn't really need to do much other than determine whether a username contains a bad word. As far as `$isbad` goes, that was for debugging. This is my new code which is still not final and only for debugging: `function containsBad($st) {
  $badwords = file("badwords.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
  foreach($badwords as $word) {
   if (strpos($st, $word) === true || strpos($st, $word) > -1) {
    return "true";
   }
  }
  return "false";
 }
 
 echo containsBad("test");`